# Prime factors edit

Tags: python, prime-factoring

I have this code

```
def primefactor(n):
    d = 2
    factors = [ ]
    while n > 1:
      if n % d == 0:
        primefactors.append(d)
        n = n//d
      else:
          primefactors.append(d)
    return factors

print(factor1(20))
[2, 2, 5]
```

Every time I delete a line, nothing prints out. Even though something should. Is there a more efficient way to get all the prime factors of a number without using any libraries??.

Comment: What line and where are you deleting? How are you printing given that there is not print statement in this function?

Comment: for example I delete the else statement and nothing printed

Comment: @nick this code runs into an infinite loop for most numbers (anything which is not a power of 2)... you should increment `d`. Further, if `d` is not a factor you should **not** add it to `factors`. And last, you wrote in the title "prime" - I don't see any prime check in this code.

Comment: yes, thats why I was asking if there is a better way to do this. Also what do you mean by you don't see any prime check

Comment: What @alfasin meant is that you ask about "_prime_" factors but your code doesn't check whether a number _is_ prime or not.  Some feedback: while you showed your code (thank you) the (scarce) textual explanations are unclear, as you can see by comments.  You got great answers for this question, but in the future try to imagine how things read for strangers who have no idea what you are doing. Writing good questions isn't easy.  [Stackoverflow help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) has useful pages (for instance, [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)), and links to more.

Comment: My program finds you prime factors for any number. I do not understand this follow up and the goal of your target program. Please clarify. Your "added" code doesn't do anything what you intended it to do.

Comment: More feedback.  Once you post a question and comments come it is OK to edit the question, to improve what people ask you about and what isn't clear.  But as answers start coming in it is better to _not_ tweak the question any more since that way you will likely invalidate what people answered.  (Very small tweaks can change the question in a way that's hard to tell.)  In this case, your added code makes this question morph into something else.  It makes it a moving target; you don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses both your original idea and the post of @user1767754

```
def factor1(n):
    primelist = lambda n: [x for x in xrange(2, n) if not 0 in map(lambda z : x % z, xrange(2,x))]
    factors = [ ]
    for d in primelist(n):
        if n % d == 0:
            factors.append(d)
    return factors
```

The program uses the `primelist` function to generate all prime numbers until the number n for which it's looking for prime factors. For each of these numbers it checks for divisibility like before and appends the prime factor to `factors` list.

As for your original code, like @alfasin said in the comment, your program goes into infinite loop for most cases, it also doesn't check for all the prime factors, and adds potential non-prime factors to the result.

A simpler, but not elegant solution to the prime number finding issue would be for instance an additional function as follows:

```
def get_primes(n):
    primelist = []
    for d1 in range(2,n):
        flag = 0
        for d2 in range(2,d1):
            if d1 % d2 is 0:
                flag = 1
                break
        if flag is 0:
            primelist.append(d1)
    return primelist
```

Here as in the lambda, the program checks the divisibility of each number until target number n with all numbers smaller than the current one. The flag is used to signal whether the number that is currently processed was found divisible by anything (besides 1 and itself). The flag is given a value 1 if it was and reset for every new number. The result is exactly as from the lambda - a list of prime numbers up to the target number and can be used as follows,

```
def factor1(n):
    factors = [ ]
    primelist = get_primes(n)
    for d in primelist:
        if n % d == 0:
            factors.append(d)
    return factors
```

In the future, just keep in mind that the nested loop solution is not ideal and should be replaced by list comprehensions, lambdas, maps, and the like.

Comment: :D I'm glad that someone finally answered the real question.

Comment: I'm confused as to that the `d+=1` is doing and why it is not indented in further

Comment: @atru a simpler version help a lot, without lambda and map

Comment: @nick did this help you? Do you have any more questions/comments?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fun one to calculate primes using `lambda` and `map`

```
limit = 100
primelist = lambda n : [x for x in range(2, n) if not 0 in map(lambda z : x % z, range(2,x))]
print ", ".join(map(str, primelist(limit)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple program to compute the prime factors of a number:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Mar 13 2017, 20:56:15)
[GCC 5.4.0] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def factors(n):
...     f, fs = 2, []
...     while f*f <= n:
...         if n % f == 0:
...             fs.append(f)
...             n /= f
...         else:
...             f += 1
...     fs.append(n)
...     return fs
...
>>> factors(20)
[2, 2, 5]
```

If *n* is large, there are better ways to find its factors: google for "Pollard rho", "elliptic curve factorization", or "quadratic sieve".

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
def primefactors(N):
    factors = []
    i = 2
    while i <= N:
        while N % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
            N = N/i
        i += 1
    return factors
```

But remember that this method will execute `N` steps thus the time efficiency is exponential with respect to the input size.

Comment: why are you using limiting the outermost iteration to `int(n**.5)+1`? it'll never reach 5, it actually will fail for every prime number, right? it's different to check for primality than to compute the prime factors.